# Is there a way to use variable as URL in a MDX markdown link tag?

Tags: docusaurus, mdxjs

I am trying to use variables to manage links inside my documentation. I have declared an object that contains all my links like that:

```
export const Links = {
  "foo": "bar",
  "bar": "https://external.goo.com"
}
```

And I try to use those variables as link uri in a markdown link tag `[Description]({Links.foo})`

The issue is that MDX seems to not interpret the variable inside the `()` so the rendered content has this result :

```
export const Links = {
  "foo": "bar",
  "bar": "https://external.goo.com"
}

[the url should be bar, but is literal {foo}]({foo})
```

I managed to use variables using `<a href={Links.foo}>this render variables correctly</a>` but this is longer and less user friendly than using the `[]()` syntax.

Is there a way to make this work (or maybe to override something in the MDX redering?) ?

*Please, bear in mind that I am not a Javascript developper, so don't assume extended knowledge on that part from me :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative I used [markdown reference style links](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#reference-style-links).

As I am using [docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/) I use the [docusaurus markdown pre-processor](https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/docusaurus-config#preprocessor) to inject a file that contains all markdown references.

This gives something like this

in `foo.mdx`

```
Checkout [my cool site][cool-site]
```

in `_global_file_links.mdx`

```
[cool-site]: https://my-cool-site.io "My cool site"
```

With the preprocessor I inject the `_global_file_links.mdx` at the end of each markdown file, all used reference gets rendered and the one not used are discarded.

Here is the preprocessor config in `docusaurus.config.js`:

```js
const config = {
  // ...
  markdown: {
    format: "mdx",
    preprocessor: ({ filePath, fileContent }) => {
      console.log("Injecting global markdown references into " + filePath);
      const fs = require("node:fs");
      const links = fs.readFileSync("./docs/_global_file_links.mdx");
      return fileContent + "\n" + links;
    },
  },
  // ...
}
```

This is a dirty fix that works, but I think at this stage It should be a docusaurus plugin. (But I'm not a JS dev, so `-_o_-`)